# How can I resolve App stuck on Splash Screen

Tags: android

Good day,

My application was working for months now, but all of a sudden it is stuck on splash screen, when using both Android Studio and the live App on Google Play. And I haven't done any change to the app of resent.

Please, anyone help?

Below is the logcat debug result. Thank you

```
04-08 12:55:42.685 5650-5650/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
04-08 12:55:42.818 5650-5650/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
04-08 12:55:42.819 5650-5650/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets I/MultiDex: Installing application
04-08 12:55:42.819 5650-5650/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
04-08 12:55:42.875 5650-5665/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
04-08 12:55:43.172 5650-5672/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
04-08 12:55:43.175 5650-5650/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
04-08 12:55:43.175 5650-5650/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
04-08 12:55:43.211 5650-5672/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
04-08 12:55:43.212 5650-5672/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
04-08 12:55:43.223 5650-5650/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets W/com.facebook.UserSettingsManager: Please set a value for AutoLogAppEventsEnabled. Set the flag to TRUE if you want to collect app install, app launch and in-app purchase events automatically. To request user consent before collecting data, set the flag value to FALSE, then change to TRUE once user consent is received. Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-android#disable-auto-events.
04-08 12:55:43.223 5650-5650/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets W/com.facebook.UserSettingsManager: You haven't set a value for AdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled. Set the flag to TRUE if you want to collect Advertiser ID for better advertising and analytics results. To request user consent before collecting data, set the flag value to FALSE, then change to TRUE once user consent is received. Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-android#disable-auto-events.
04-08 12:55:43.307 5650-5650/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets I/Hash: Generating for fb.....
04-08 12:55:43.310 5650-5650/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets I/Hashkey: WyU474QvS8TLhPp4Dfi/GTzGyOA=
04-08 12:55:43.355 5650-5679/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 16250
04-08 12:55:43.355 5650-5679/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
04-08 12:55:43.355 5650-5679/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.remmy.wisdomnuggets
04-08 12:55:43.355 5650-5679/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
04-08 12:55:44.748 5650-5650/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
04-08 12:55:44.812 5650-5650/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>
04-08 12:55:44.812 5650-5650/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>
04-08 12:55:45.042 5650-5650/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets E/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets.ManagementUtil.Management: Setting : Working
04-08 12:55:45.042 5650-5650/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets E/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets.DatabaseUtil.DbQuery: Setting : Working
04-08 12:55:45.042 5650-5650/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets E/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets.DatabaseUtil.FavouriteQueries: Setting : Working
04-08 12:55:45.042 5650-5650/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets E/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets.DatabaseUtil.FileQueries: Setting : Working
04-08 12:55:45.043 5650-5650/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets E/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets.DatabaseUtil.DownloadQueries: Setting : Working
04-08 12:55:45.043 5650-5650/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets E/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets.DatabaseUtil.Mp3Queries: Setting : Working
04-08 12:55:45.043 5650-5650/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets E/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets.DatabaseUtil.PurchaseQueries: Setting : Working
04-08 12:55:45.043 5650-5650/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets E/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets.DatabaseUtil.QueryFactory: Setting : Working
04-08 12:55:45.043 5650-5650/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets E/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets.DatabaseUtil.QueryRunner: Setting : Working
04-08 12:55:45.058 5650-5650/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets E/JSON: {"functionality":"admob_configuration"}
04-08 12:55:45.060 5650-5650/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets E/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets.ManagementUtil.Management: Setting : RequestObject{serverUrl='null', requestType='null', photoKeyword='null', perPage='60', page='1', pictureId='null', json='{"functionality":"admob_configuration"}', firstRequest=true, connectionType=UI, connection=ADMOB}
04-08 12:55:45.110 5650-5679/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
04-08 12:55:45.121 5650-5679/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=Splash, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-9200293164657975561}]
04-08 12:55:45.129 5650-5718/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
04-08 12:55:45.913 5650-5718/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-08 12:55:45.914 5650-5718/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
04-08 12:55:45.942 5650-5718/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xaa9d34c0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
04-08 12:55:45.989 5650-5718/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa9d34c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9dd59780)
04-08 12:55:46.020 5650-5725/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
04-08 12:55:46.021 5650-5672/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
04-08 12:55:46.021 5650-5672/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
04-08 12:55:46.021 5650-5672/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
04-08 12:55:46.073 5650-5718/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa9d34c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9dd59780)
04-08 12:55:46.629 5650-5650/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets I/Choreographer: Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-08 12:55:49.141 5650-5712/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets E/MK Request 2: POST
04-08 12:55:50.189 5650-5712/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets E/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets.ConnectionUtil.Connection: Working : 
04-08 12:55:50.190 5650-5712/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets E/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets.ConnectionUtil.Connection: POST 200 http://remmyhazzan.com.ng/wisdomnuggets/books4u_home.php {"functionality":"admob_configuration"}
04-08 12:55:50.197 5650-5650/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets E/com.remmy.wisdomnuggets.ConnectionUtil.ConnectionBuilder: Response =
```

Comment: _"How can I resolve App stuck on Splash Screen"_ By debugging the code in the splash screen (or elsewhere) that should take your app away from the splash screen and observing why it doesn't exit the splash screen. Or you could add the relevant code to the question, but we probably can't tell what has changed outside that code.

Comment: Good day,

Thank you for your response.

I figured out that I can access the app without internet, but since the app needs to connect to the server, most of the functions will not work.

But when I connect to the internet and try to open the app, it remains at the splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

if you didn't changed anything in your app (an we are talking even about app distributed by Google Play) then clearly there is a problem by server side

there is a chance that some network/server side response is just broken, I see you are requesting for something (`RequestObject`), but also see `serverUrl='null'`, so app may not be configured properly. Also last words of this log is `ConnectionBuilder: Response =` and... what is the response?

there is no `Exception` word in block of text posted in question, so app hangs on splash because of wrong logic in code (maybe not aware of some null parameters)

there is also a chance that you are using 3rd party lib connecting to some services (I see Firebase in logs), which is currently deprecated

without line of code all this is guessing...

PS. learn how to post readable logs...

Comment: Good day,

Thank you for your response.

I figured out that I can access the app without internet, but since the app needs to connect to the server, most of the functions will not work.

But when I connect to the internet and try to open the app, it remains at the splash screen.